# Machine Learning: how to correctly calculate gradient descent for simple linear problem

Tags: machine-learning, linear-algebra

So, I was trying to learn machine learning, and, after watching a couple of Andrew Ng's lectures decided to try and write a simple piece of code to determine what someone's salary would be based on the number of years they worked at a company by this simple linear function:

salary = w1 * numberOfYears + w0

I then used the least square method to calculate the error between the predicted results and the actual results and tried to minimize the error of the gradient of that function:

Error = (1/2) [ sum of (predicted - actual)^2 for all samples (x, y) ]

The predicted value is the one calculated by the linear equation above, and actual = y.  w1 and w0 are weights to the function that are set to some initial values (0 and 0 for example) and are changed to decrease the error throughout the process of gradient descent.

Steps to the algorithm:

1)  Choose some (random) initial values for the model parameters (w).
2)  Calculate the gradient G of the error function with respect to each model parameter.
3)  Change the model parameters so that we move a short distance in the direction of the greatest rate of decrease of the error, i.e., in the direction of -G.
4)  Repeat steps 2 and 3 until G gets close to zero.

In my implementation I have this code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < numSamples; i++) {
    double error = prediction(data.X[i]) - data.Y[i];
    while(nearsZero(error)) {
        for(int j = 0; j < w.length; j++) {
            w[j] -=  0.1 * error * data.X[i][j];
        }
        error = data.Y[i] - prediction(data.X[i]);
    }
}
```

If I run this with only one sample (meaning ignore the outermost loop), then the weights continuously subtract a value that is continuously nearing infinity (or -infinity).  If I change the w[j] -= ... to a w[j] += ... then the function works for the first value and sets initial w that will solve it for one sample (but that isn't what I was supposed to do as far as I can tell).  Also, when I add multiple samples the numbers just do the same thing on the second sample that they were doing on the first sample when I had -=.

I feel like gradient descent doesn't make sense here because it was demoed on graphs like z=y^2+x^2, which looks like a big bowl with one central min that it will find eventually.

On the graph in my problem the graph looks like a parabola that extends to infinity in both directions and has infinite min values along a line.

I'm not sure what it is that I am doing wrong, but I would assume that it's something to do with my understanding of the problem.  If anyone knows how to get this working I would appreciate it.

**EDIT:** Updated data.X[i] in the while loop to data.X[i][j].  Each data point i should have some value Y[i] and an array of X values at X[i].

Answer (score 3):

First off, your gradient is `error*x1` with respect to w1, but not to w0. The gradient for w0 is just `error`.

Second, you're computing `error` with the wrong sign. It should be `predicted - actual`, not the other way around. What you're doing is essentially *adding* the gradient at every step.

Comment: In this row
  w[j] -=  0.1 * error * data.X[i]; . Shouldn't  data.X[i] be different for each w[j] in terms of j?

Comment: Yes, X should have had 'j'.  I corrected it in the question.  x0 is always equal to one, therefore w0 = error * x0 = error.  That is just a convention I carried over from them being in matrices.  I switched to predicted - actual, but it still does the same thing.  I end up getting NaN for my weights sometime during the while loop on the second sample.